# Tell web references to use web.config or how to make settings.settings editable

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, ssrs-2008, settings.settings

I am migrating an ASP.NET 2.0 (3.5 SP1) app to .NET 4.0. It leverages SQL Server Reporting Services 2008R2 web service. This web service is an old-school asmx soap web service.

Back then I added a web-reference which I set to dynamic and this opted in some configuration code in my `<applicationSettings>` of the `web.config`.

After migrating to Visual Studio 2010 and .Net 4.0 I had to re-add the web reference. The .Net 2.0 web references dialog adds the proxy class as it was. But now it includes a `settings.settings` file to my project in the `Properties` folder. I could live with that but the `settings.settings` file is not available after compilation. It looks like it has been compiled into the dll.

Even pasting the `settings.settings` config in my `web.config` and deleting the `settings.settings` file does not help. I get a namespace compilation error because the vs-generated proxy class expected the `settings.settings`...

So how can I include my web reference and make it adjustable within a configuration file?

Either tell the web reference editor to use `web.config`, maybe?
Or make the `settings.settings` file available as xml so it could be changed on deployment?

Or any other help would be fantastic too...

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help you but this is our approach to web services to get around this problem.  We create a wrapper class for a given web service and, every time we instantiate the proxy class, we set the URL in code referencing the `<appSettings />` node.

e.g.

```
public class MyWebService
{
  private static readonly string _serviceUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUrl"] ?? "http://someserviceurl.com/service.asmx";

  public MyWebService()
  {
  }

  private WebServiceClient GetClient()
  {
    WebServiceClient client = new WebServiceClient();
    client.Url = _serviceUrl;
    return client;
  }

  private void Method1()
  {
    var client = GetClient();
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. For those of us unfortunate enough to deal with this, there is no way to override settings.settings that I can find other than this solution.

Comment: One additional comment, you need 2 URLs for SSRS: The Execution Service URL (something like http://servername/ReportServer/ReportExecution2005.asmx) and the Report Service URL (something like http://servername/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx).